# calling the directive twice is sharing the same scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I am using the following angular plugin to generate the query.

[angular query builder](http://ngmodules.org/modules/angular-query-builder)

the issue I am getting is when I use the directive twice. one after another all the function if I use in first happens to another as well.

```
<div class="container" ng-controller="QueryBuilderCtrl">
<h1>Angular.js Query Builder</h1>

    <div class="alert alert-info">
        <strong>Example Output</strong><br>
        <span ng-bind-html="output"></span>
    </div>

    <query-builder group="filter.group"></query-builder>
    <query-builder group="filter.group"></query-builder>
</div>
```

Its a piece of code from index page of the plugin. Here I copy pasted the querybuilder directive twice. But its sharing the same scope.

How to fix this issue.

Comment: It seems, that's because you're passing exactly the same data (`filter.group`)  and the `filter` object is passed by reference. It means, all changes of `filter.group` made in the first directive are actual for the second directive.

Comment: how to fix this. as the directive need to be added runtime on button click.

Comment: You can pass a copy of `filter.group` each time. But there's no controller code to see and be sure.

Answer (score 0):

Try giving different model to directives. In your case they are sharing same model.

```
<div class="container" ng-controller="QueryBuilderCtrl">
<h1>Angular.js Query Builder</h1>

    <div class="alert alert-info">
        <strong>Example Output</strong><br>
        <span ng-bind-html="output"></span>
    </div>

    <query-builder group="filter.group"></query-builder>
    <query-builder group="filter.anotherGroup"></query-builder>
</div>
```

Comment: actually thats not possible , because directives need to be added runtime. and filter.group is fixed in the controller.